# Cannot upgrade FROM High Serra 10.13.6 to Mojave 10.14.6?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Xcode from 10.1 to 11.0. Somewhere it says that I have to have iOS 10.14.6. (Currently my Mac is running High Sierra 10.13.6. And I have trouble to make Xcode 10.1 work with my iPhone 7 whiting is running 13.1.2.)

When I am trying to download macOS Mojave, I see the following message. After click OK, it seems that nothing happens.

I have MacBook Pro 2018.

What can I do to move forward?

[image]

Comment: Ummm, that is not an error coming from MacOS. That is something else, perhaps VMWare Fusion.

Comment: That's a message from JAMF.  The machine you think you should be installing a later OS on is not yours, and is managed by someone else.

Comment: The mac is a company item. It has quite some software installed from JAMF. I have admin right on this mac. We reinstalled latest VMWare, Symantec, Juno, webEx. Still has the same message.

Answer (score 1):

If you have internet, you could boot to recovery and install the latest OS that your Mac is able to run (which is 10.14.6 right now). Power off your Mac and hold the following keys only right after you power on and until you see the Apple or the globe. You will need to connect to the internet (wired or wireless) for this to work.

- Option-⌘-R

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

That will get you a free and clear installer that will run through the checks and if it fails, you will also have the ability to run Disk Utility from the installer to repair things if this is just a filesystem error causing the grief.

The Self Service app means you might be on an MDM managed application like with JAMF Pro, so if this is a work machine, be sure to check with your team to be sure there isn't a restriction preventing the upgrade.

Comment: The are some certificate issues that took forever to fix. IT ended up reformat the disk and installed Mojave and everything else. Then I download Xcode 11 with no issue. After that sideloading to iphone 7 was successful.

The mac is on a windows domain. I changed password on other computers. I also installed Visual Studio for Mac. and configured Xmarin etc... No sure which one has contributed the complications...